# Difference between using the property of an object directly and returning using a function

Tags: javascript

In Mozilla MDN

I have following example

```
var Animal = {
  type: "Invertebrates", // Default value of properties
  displayType : function() {  // Method which will display type of Animal
    return this.type;
  }


}
```

So if I do

`console.log(Animal.displayType());  \\Invertebrates`

and

`console.log(Animal.type);  \\Invertebrates`

Both the out put are same so what is the point of using a method to return the property of the function

Or what would be the right way to return an internal property of an object , Directly or using a function  ?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: In this case, not much. In other cases there could be a use, IE doing some kind of data manipulation to the property before it's returned.

Comment: @tymeJV thank you , I know its a silly question but since I am trying to learn JS in depth felt its good to asks  doubts  here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that this function may compute what it returns, rather than read it from a property.

In general, functions like this, getters and setters, are said to enhance encapsulation and make your design more resilient against change. In addition to this, setters may trigger events, something that simple assignment to a property can't do.

By the way, the name 'property' in JS is very unfortunate, since in fact, in all other languages a property IS something only accessible via a getter and a setter.

Accessing attributes only via functions came in fashion when java beans were invented, to facilitate use of a tool called a bean box. Never mind what that is.

Applying getters and setters everywhere is wicked and totally unnecessary. It may easily slow your  program down by factors.

They are very powerful, WHEN YOU NEED THEM, for the reasons I described. Don't only think at your current design, but also about future modifications. But adding getters and setters everywhere, in addition to making your code slow, will also make the amount of source code explode, which is in itself a hindrance to future modifications.

So you can use them if you deem it fit, but prefer common sense above all...

Comment: even after reading Object oriented Js a bit I still feel function based implementations are faster , Although for huge form validation or SPA , I think Object oriented approach is more applicable

Answer (score 0):

The difference is when you pass them around. If I pass Animal.type to a function, I get the type immediatly, but if I pass the function I can then run it later and get the type at a future point.

Imagine I have an AJAX call in my code, and in the success method I want to do something based on the type. If I pass the type into my function, it could potentially change before the success function is called. In this case, having a function is better because we can calculate the type at the time the success happens.

Consider the following code:-

```
function test(typeProp, typeFunc) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/GetTest',
        success: function() {
            if(typeProp === 'Cat') {
                //do something
            }
            if(typeFunc() === 'Cat') {
                //do something
            }
        }
    })
}

var Animal = {
  type: "Cat", // Default value of properties
  displayType : function() {  // Method which will display type of Animal
    return this.type;
  }

test(animal.type, animal.displayType);
animal.type = 'Dog';
```

Once the code gets to the success function, typeProp will be 'Cat', but typeFunc will return 'Dog';

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you want to use its property to return some other information:

Example: You have a mapping of "Invertebrates" which returns the description of the word (dictionnary). Thus by calling displayDefinition() it will give you the definition

```
  displayDefinition: function() {  
    return dictionnaryFind(this.type);
  }
```